# Script for Bitlocker in Active Directory domain

Tags: powershell, encryption, active-directory, bitlocker

I need to configure the script to run in the domain, I tried a bunch of options, Enable-Bitlocker, ps1, I also changed the bitlocker launch group policy. I would like to clarify what commands should be prescribed for encrypting a computer, as well as whether it is possible to write a password in the script that will be set for encryption.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Never, ever put credentials in scripts. You are just asking for unnecessary trouble. Either ask for them each time using Get-Credential, use a ScheduledTask with the needed creds, or already have creds in SecretsManger for retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of an article about scripts that enable bitlocker and set a random PIN: https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33771/We-have-bitlocker-so-we-need-MBAM-too.html
Have a look.

Comment: Is it possible to set a strong password instead of a random one?

Comment: How to set a single password for everyone, is there a script for 10 computers in AD?

Comment: It is not recommendable to use a password. The PIN is secure enough since it cannot be brute forced. Using a password would mean not to use the TPM chip, which has other downsides, please abandon that idea. Setting the same PIN for all is possible, change the first line to $pin="123567" or whatever PIN.